# about Entity Framework 4 caching 2-st level

Tags: caching, entity-framework-4

Where can I find the second-level caching features in Entity Framework 4?
Articles found only on the use of examples, but I would like to know whether you can configure caching and what you can do it set up?

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't have 2nd level caching. The only way to get 2nd level cache is to use [EF Caching provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32).